Pullback of an ample bundle under an embedding is ample
In Example 11.8 on JP Demailly's book on Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry it is being said that

The pullback of a (very) ample line bundle by an embedding is clearly also (very) ample.

I was trying to prove this result, but I could not put the pieces together. If $f : X \to Y$ is an embedding of compact complex manifolds and $L \to Y$ a holomorphic line bundle that is ample, then $L^{\otimes k}$ is very ample and thus yields an embedding of $Y$ into $\Bbb CP^N$.
To show that $f^*L$ is ample, one needs to prove that $(f^\ast L)^{\otimes k}$ is very ample , that is $(f^\ast L)^{\otimes m}$ separates points and directions.
Since $L^{\otimes k}$ is very ample, it separates points, this means that for any distinct $p,q \in Y$, there exists a section $s$ of $L^{\otimes k}$ such that $s(p) = 0$ and $s(q) \ne 0$. Will $(f^\ast s)(x)=s(f(x))$ and $(f^\ast s)(y)=s(f(y))$ satisfy these conditions for distinct $x,y \in X$ also?
How do we argue that for $p \in X$ that is not a basepoint and $v \in T^{1,0}_pX$ there exists a holomorphic section $s$ of $f^\ast L$ such that $s(p) = 0$ and $ds_p \ne 0$?

If the map $Y \to \mathbf P^N$ induced by $\mathscr L^{\otimes k}$ is an embedding, then the same goes for its restriction to $X$. This is more or less the map induced by $f^\mathscr L$, except there might be even more global sections on $X$ that don't lift to $Y$. That means that $f^\mathscr L$ defines a map $X \to \mathbf P^M$ for $M \geq N$ and a linear projection $\mathbf P^M \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^N$ such that the composite $X \to \mathbf P^M \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^N$ is everywhere defined and a closed immersion, so $X \to \mathbf P^M$ is a closed immersion as well.
